# Snapd won't install on Ubuntu 16.04 VPS

Tags: snap, vps, squashfs

I can't get snap to work on an Ubuntu 16.04 vps.
I get this output when trying to install:

```
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
  snapd
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 13.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 65.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 snapd amd64 2.42.1 [13.2 MB]
Fetched 13.2 MB in 2s (5204 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package snapd.
(Reading database ... 71733 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.42.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd (2.42.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up snapd (2.42.1) ...
snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
```

When trying to install the hello-world snap it gives me this error:

```
    snap install hello-world
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using
       "squashfs": mount: /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-948900179: mount failed:
       Unknown error -1
```

I have looked everywhere for a solution but for the life of me have not been able to find one.